# Apply same encryption & decryption in both Angular and ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, angular, encryption, asp.net-core-mvc

[image]

In C#, I am using this scheme for encryption and decryption. I want to apply the same on the Angular side - how can I do that?

Actually, when I call the API I want to send the encrypted value to the backend and in backend I want to decrypt it to process further.

Is there any way or alternative please?

Frontend call goes here:

```
callExternalProject(Username : string): Observable<any> {
      
       return this.http.get<any>(`${environment.CMRDashboardURL}/Account/LoginUser?username=${I_WantToPassEncryptedUsernameHere}`) .pipe(
          catchError(error => {
          return throwError(() => new Error(error))
          })     
        );
}
```

Applying same encryption decryption in Angular (frontend) and C# (ASP.NET Core MVC) side.

Comment: _"I want to apply the same on the Angular side"_ - but why? Anyone can look at your code, and execute the JavaScript to encrypt the username "admin", and they'll be logged in as admin. This does not offer any security.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular component, you can import the `crypto-js` and then decrypt the value. Refer to the following code ([View the online Sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/encryption-decryption-triple-des-angular-ebrck8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fencryption.service.ts)):

encryption.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class EncryptionService {
  key: any = 'sz83kd75';
  IV = 'MTIzNDU2Nzg=';

  // ENCRYPTION USING CBC TRIPLE DES
  encryptUsingTripleDES(res: any, typeObj: boolean): string {
    const data = typeObj ? JSON.stringify(res) : res;
    const keyHex = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(this.key);
    const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(this.IV);
    console.log(iv);
    const mode = CryptoJS.mode.CBC;
    const encrypted = CryptoJS.TripleDES.encrypt(data, keyHex, { iv, mode });
    return encrypted.toString();
  }

  // DECRYPTION USING CBC TRIPLE DES
  decryptUsingTripleDES(encrypted: string): string {
    const keyHex = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(this.key);
    const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(this.IV);
    const mode = CryptoJS.mode.CBC;
    const decrypted = CryptoJS.TripleDES.decrypt(encrypted, keyHex, {
      iv,
      mode,
    });
    return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
  }

  // ENCRYPTION USING AES
  encryptUsingAES(res: any, typeObj: boolean): string {
    const data = typeObj ? JSON.stringify(res) : res;
    const hash = CryptoJS.MD5(this.key).toString();
    const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, hash);
    return encrypted.toString();
  }

  // DECRYPTION USING AES
  decryptUsingAES(encrypted: string): string {
    const hash = CryptoJS.MD5(this.key).toString();
    const decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, hash);
    return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
  }
}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EncryptionService } from './encryption.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private encryption: EncryptionService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const data = 'test1231!';
    // // DES
    const encrypted = this.encryption.encryptUsingTripleDES(data, true);
    console.log(encrypted);
    const decrypted = this.encryption.decryptUsingTripleDES(encrypted);
    console.log(decrypted);
  }
}
```

After getting the encrypted data, you can call the controller method and try to use the following code to decrypt the data.

```
    static byte[] key = null;
    static byte[] iv = null;
    public static string Decrypt(string value)
    {
        DESCryptoServiceProvider desSprovider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
        Encoding utf1 = new UTF8Encoding();
        key = utf1.GetBytes("sz83kd75");
        iv = utf1.GetBytes("MTIzNDU2Nzg=");
        ICryptoTransform decryptor = desSprovider.CreateDecryptor(key, iv);

        Encoding utf = new UTF8Encoding();
        value = value.Replace(" ", "+").Replace("'", "");

        byte[] bEncrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
        byte[] bDecrupt = decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(bEncrypt, 0, bEncrypt.Length);
        return utf.GetString(bDecrupt);
    }
```

The test result as below:

[image]